# MSBuild Conditional Imports

Tags: .net, asp.net, msbuild, import

Is there a workaround for conditional imports in MSBuild?

I've found evidence [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/a48b5b57-215c-44f9-b750-106efe3ea023) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/d5acb498-6d87-4063-86e8-245dcb7d9dcb) detailing a bug in the MSBuild IDE interface.  In particular, `Import` statements do not reload when building:

> This is a known limitation.  VS will only ever process the  tags once, when the project is loaded.  So whatever  tag is active at the time the project is first loaded (based on whatever values your properties have at that time)... that's the  tag that you will get for the lifetime of that project in the IDE

For example, I might want to import the `bar` or `baz` project based on the value of `foo`:

```
<Import Project="bar.targets" Condition="'$(foo)' == 'bar'" />
<Import Project="baz.targets" Condition="'$(foo)' == 'baz'" />
```

Is there a workaround or different approach I can use for accomplishing the desired functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can overcome this using the conditional import mechaism. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi

My Book: [Inside the Microsoft Build Engine : Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626286)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what is in your targets files, but if you are just setting properties based on the $(foo) property then you could use a prebuild event, or prebuild target to do the same job.